# Placing A Word in a string at end of word

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to write a function that will modify a string in the following way:

If the string has 'The ' at the very beginning, I want to cut it out and add ', The' to the end of the string.

My code doesn't work - I would like to know how to fix it so that it works.

```
<?php

    $string = 'Wonderful World of Disney';
    $search_term = 'The ';
    $str_replace = ', The';
    $pos = strpos($string, $search_term);
    if ($pos==0 && strlen($string) > 4) {
        $clean_str = substr($string, 4, strlen($string));
        $clean_str = $clean_str . $str_replace;
        echo $clean_str;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your string doesn't begin with `'The '`.

Comment: Was just an example. I tested it out with a lot of different strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using regular expressions might be better for this task:

```
$clean_str = preg_replace('/^The (.*)$/', '$1, The', $string);
```

Also, your code is not working because you need to to [strict comparison](http://php.net/manual/language.operators.comparison.php) on the result of [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos):

```
if ($pos === 0 && strlen($string) > 4) {
// ...
```